# Install module from gist URL

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to install a module by using a url to a github gist? I think it used to be possible with PsGet, but now PowerShellGet supersedes it and doesn't have this option. I saw there's GistProvider, but that just downloads the files to a folder, so they are not really part of the module system.